# How do I find all the devices connected to my home network using Android?

Tags: android

As part of a project I'm building an app that maps the home network, I found the following code but I can not find help all devices which are connected to the network (IP addresses).

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    LoopCurrentIP = 0;

    String IPAddress = "";
    String[] myIPArray = aurl[0].split("\\.");
    InetAddress currentPingAddr;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        try {
            // build the next IP address
            currentPingAddr = InetAddress.getByName(myIPArray[0] + "." +
                    myIPArray[1] + "." +
                    myIPArray[2] + "." +
                    Integer.toString(LoopCurrentIP));
            IPAddress = currentPingAddr.toString();
            publishProgress(""+(int)((i*100)/255));                         
            Log.d("MyApp",IPAddress);  

            // 50ms Timeout for the "ping"
            if (currentPingAddr.isReachable(1000)) {
                textView.setText(currentPingAddr.toString());
                ret.add(currentPingAddr);

                Log.d("MyApp",IPAddress);                     
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        LoopCurrentIP++;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there any error come ?

Comment: In other words, what happens when you run that code?

Comment: The [MuilticastSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) API should help you with this.

Comment: No, but I can not find ip address

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn Return empty list

Comment: Return empty list? Where are you expecting the return of anything? Which list? That doesn't make sense =/ I think, with **absolutely** no offense intended, that you don't understand the code you posted. Maybe a little more research is in order!

Comment: I have a global variable called ret which held the list, the function returns null but the list should be updated in this Code section.